# Picasso's fit().centreCrop() inserts space in GridView

Tags: android, android-gridview, picasso

Am using Picasso to populate my GridView, using this code:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(585, 585));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }


        Picasso.with(mContext)
                .load(photoUrls.get(position))                    
                .into(imageView);


    return imageView;
}
```

and my GridView looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/galleryGridView"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:numColumns="2"
   android:columnWidth="90dp"
   android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
   android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
   android:gravity="center"
   android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >

</GridView>
```

But as you can see, some of the images overlap.

[image]

So I added `fit().centerCrop()`:

```
Picasso.with(mContext)
            .load(photoUrls.get(position))
            .fit().centerCrop()
            .into(imageView);
```

Now the images are well aligned but a huge space has opened up:

[image]

Not sure what I need to do now.I've tried changing the layout width/height with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved this by removing the padding:

```
imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
```

and `fit()` method

```
.fit().centerCrop()
```

so my `getView()` method now looks like this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(585, 585));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }


        Picasso.with(mContext)
                .load(photoUrls.get(position))

                .into(imageView);


    return imageView;
}
```